# Explanation of assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, floppy

I have started to learn assembly. I came across these lines.

```
;*************************************************;
;   OEM Parameter block / BIOS Parameter Block
;*************************************************;

TIMES 0Bh-$+start DB 0

bpbBytesPerSector:      DW 512
bpbSectorsPerCluster:   DB 1
bpbReservedSectors:     DW 1
```

I am confused on the first line of declaration
 "bpbBytesPerSector:    DW 512" . Here I think DW is define word. So DW 512 means defining 512 words means 1024 bytes. Now the label is "bpbBytesPerSector". Bytes per sector should be 512(this is what I think). Similarly I can't understand next two lines.
I am totally confused on this. Can anybody explain me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `dw` means define the *single* word 512. That means allocate space for *one* word here and set the value to 512.

This is creating a BIOS parameter block (BPB) and breaking it down:

```
0000                         TIMES 0Bh-$+start DB 0     ; allocate 11 zero bytes.
000B  bpbBytesPerSector:     DW 512                     ; define one word 512
000D  bpbSectorsPerCluster:  DB 1                       ; define one byte 1
000E  bpbReservedSectors:    DW 1                       ; define one word 1
0010
```

Answer (score 0):

As @paxdiablo already pointed out, the number is just the value for the word. When/if you want to define an array of 512 words like you described, you'd use something like:

```
myarray dw 512 dup(?)
```

Here the `512` is the number of repetitions, and the `?` is the value to be put in each ("?" means "leave it uninitialized", but you can specify a value if you prefer).